# Filter multiple results from database in view in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

## **What I'm trying to do:**

I have a table full of sponsorship kids and I would like the users to filter them by Location, Gender and more. *Just starting out with those 2 for the moment. Will add more filters later.*

## **What is currently working:**

**On my Filter form**

```
  <form action="{{ route('child-sponsorship-filter') }}" method="get">
  @csrf
    Location
            <select name="location">
              <option value="">No Preference</option>
                @foreach ($country as $c)
              <option value="{{$c->country_name}}">{{$c->country_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        
        
          Gender
            <select name="gender">
              <option value="">No Preference</option>
              <option value="Male">Male</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        
                <button type="submit">Filter Results</button>
            
  </form>

    /// Begin Displays All and Filtered sponsor children
    @foreach ($sponsorKid as $sk)
    ...
    @endforeach
```

**On my KidController**

```
    public function index(){
            $country = DB::table('countries')->orderBy('country_name')->get();
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('first_name')->get();
            return view('child-sponsorship.index',compact('sponsorKid','country')); 
    }


    public function filter(Request $request){
            $location = $request->location;
            $gender = $request->gender;
            // $filter = [$location->location, $gender->gender];
            //dd($location);
        
        $country = DB::table('countries')->orderBy('country_name')->get();

        if(empty($gender) && empty($location)){
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('id')->get();

        }elseif(!empty($gender) && !empty($location)){
           $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('current_country', $location)->where('gender', $gender)->orderby('id')->get();
 
        }elseif($gender != true){
            $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('current_country', $location)->orderby('id')->get();

        }elseif($location != true){
            $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('gender', $gender)->orderby('id')->get();

        }else{
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('id')->get();
        }
        return view('child-sponsorship.index',compact('sponsorKid','country')); 
    }
```

**Kids Table**

```
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+
| id | first_name | gender | current_country |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | Emma       | Female | Haiti           |
|  2 | Lea        | Female | Nepal           |
|  3 | Matthew    | Male   | India           |
|  4 | Andrew     | Male   | Nepal           |
|  5 | CHRIS      | Male   | Haiti           |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+
```

**Countries Table**

```
+----+--------------+
| id | country_name |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Haiti        |
|  2 | India        |
|  3 | Nepal        |
+----+--------------+
```

**Routes in use**

```
Route::get('/child-sponsorship','KidController@index')->name('child-sponsorship');
Route::get('/child-sponsorship/filter','KidController@filter')->name('child-sponsorship-filter');
```

## **Issues:**

1. Do to the `@csrf` in the form I get the token in the URL.  How
   can I remove that?
   `http://xxxxxx.oo/child-sponsorship/filter?_token=jqFSC7tTmHuZ1tL8Dzz1LzNQNv5F2pOUrAa5uzs2&location=Haiti&gender=Male`
2. After selecting a filter, For example: `Location, Haiti`. I can't seem to get the current filter to stay in place on the select box after page refresh. It returns back to it's default state after page refresh. (**Do I need a 3rd route?**)
3. Can someone show me how I can update the filters via ajax without the page refresh.
4. Is there a better way to filter the query rather than using a ton of if statements?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

## **Issue #3 Update:** *(Adding Ajax)*

Okay I'm getting closer I think.

**Routes:**

```
    Route::get('/child-sponsorship','KidController@index')->name('child-sponsorship');
    Route::get('/child-sponsorship/filter','KidController@filter')->name('child-sponsorship-filter');
```

**Index View**  *(Show filter form and sponsor children)*

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label>Location</label>
        <select id="location" name="location">
            <option value="">No Preference</option>
            @foreach ($country as $c)
            <option value="{{$c->country_name}}">{{$c->country_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

    <label>Gender</label>
        <select id="gender" name="gender">
            <option value="">No Preference</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>

        <button id="ajaxSubmit">Filter Results</button>
</form>
    @foreach ($sponsorKid as $sk)
    ////.......
    @endforeach 
-----------------------------------------------------
// JS

@section('filter_js')

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('child-sponsorship-filter') }}",
        method: "get",
        data: {
           location: jQuery('#location').val(),
           gender: jQuery('#gender').val(),
       },
       success: function(result){
           console.log(result);
       }});
 });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

According to my Debug bar tool I'm getting the correct query:

`` select * from `kids` where `current_country` = 'Nepal' and `gender` = 'Female' order by `id` asc ``

But it is NOT showing correctly on the page....?
I'm also getting the correct path in my console:

`jquery.min.js:19 XHR finished loading: GET "http://xxxxxx.oo/child-sponsorship/filter?location=Nepal&gender=Female".`

What am I doing wrong here?

**These are my 2 functions in `KidController`** *(index and filter)*

```
        public function index(){ 

        $country = DB::table('countries')->distinct('country_name')->orderBy('country_name')->get();
        $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('first_name')->get();
        return view('child-sponsorship.index',compact('sponsorKid','country'));
    } 

        public function filter(Request $request){ 
             $location = $request->location;
            $gender = $request->gender;
 
        $country = DB::table('countries')->orderBy('country_name')->get();
        if(empty($gender) && empty($location)){
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('id')->get();
        }elseif(!empty($gender) && !empty($location)){
           $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('current_country', $location)->where('gender', $gender)->orderby('id')->get(); 
        }elseif($gender != true){
            $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('current_country', $location)->orderby('id')->get();
        }elseif($location != true){
            $sponsorKid = DB::table('kids')->where('gender', $gender)->orderby('id')->get();
        }else{
            $sponsorKid = Kid::orderBy('id')->get();
        }
        return view('child-sponsorship.index',compact('sponsorKid','country'));

    }
```

I'm returning the same view as I don't want it to refresh to a new page.

Comment: Regarding point no.4 check [this Laracasts video](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/15).

Comment: Regarding point no. 1, given that this is a `GET` call, there isn't need to add the `@csrf`token. This is more helpful in a `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE`call (with forms).

Comment: Regarding point no.3: Google it first. There is a ton of articles/tutorial regarding that subject. You can check [this](https://appdividend.com/2018/02/07/laravel-ajax-tutorial-example/) for example.

Comment: @HCK thanks for the Ajax link, exactly what I was looking for. Also for the `@csrf` tip. I watched that Laracast video earlier today... The constant PHPunit testing throws me off. I'll give it another look or 3.

Comment: @HCK For Issue #3 I added an update to this in my question. Would you mind taking a look?